# PHP converting strtotime into a microtime

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to find a way to make an `strtotime` with a provided datetime match up somewhat with a time generated from `microtime(true)`.

I can't quite figure it out, I've tried dividing my `strtotime` by 1000 but this doesn't quite give me the right result, how can I match them up to be identical.

```php
$time = strtotime('2022-04-06 09:00:00') / 1000;
$micro = microtime(true);
echo "$time - $micro";
```

output

```
1649260.8 - 1649233311.5081
```

Comment: microtime returns the current unix timestamp while strtotime returns the current unix timestamp of a given datetime-string.
try: `echo strtotime("now"). " - ".microtime(true);`

Comment: Hmm, strange, because `strtotime('2022-04-06 09:00:00')` gives me the output of  1649260800 which equates to Wednesday, 6 April 2022 17:00:00 which is clearly wrong, it should be 9am not 5pm?

Comment: Might be the timezone. From [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): "_Warning: The Unix timestamp that this function returns does not contain information about time zones._"

Comment: @brombeer in which case it should be UTC time, which even then is only an hour our, not 12 or so hours out :D

Comment: microtime(true) returns a float timestamp from the current time, including microseconds. The probability that a given timestamp is equal to the value returned by Microtime is almost zero. Please describe in more detail what you want to compare or achieve.

Comment: Do you want to find a time difference with milli/microseconds from a given date to the current microtime?

Comment: _"I've tried dividing my `strtotime` by 1000"_ - that makes, and so much should be obvious from the result you got, no sense - both values, the strtotime result and microtime, _are_ in seconds already. Only microtime is not an integer but a float, and has the actual micro seconds portion as decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by adding a dot and zeros to your string :

```php
$time = strtotime('2022-04-06 09:00:00');
$micro = microtime(true);
echo $time.".0000 - ".$micro;
```

Otherwise you can use the `number_format` function :

```php
$time = strtotime('2022-04-06 09:00:00');
$timemicro = number_format($time, 4, '.', '');
$micro = microtime(true);
echo $timemicro." - ".$micro;
```

These are the simplest solutions I have found :)

Comment: Is your code (here to try https://3v4l.org/BP3mY#v8.1.4 ) what the questioner is looking for?

Comment: @jspit I think that's what he was looking for, no ?